# How can I hide the status bar of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How can I hide VS' statusbar?  It flickers between 'Ready' and 'Updating JScript Intellisense...', which is distracting to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Show Status Bar`:

[image]

Comment: Oooo, I see.  thanks.  I couldn't find it on the first go (there seem to be a lot of settings)

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> [Uncheck] Show status bar -> OK